# insert id into type array mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

My `mongodb` collection `login` is structured as so:

```
email: "John.doe@gmail.com"
password: "password"
full_name: "John Doe"
list_of_docs_bought: Array
   0: "g81h8"
   1: "fursr"
```

now, in my code, what I want to do is insert a new id into the `list_of_docs_bought` array. My code is as follows:

```
let collection = database.collection('login')
let doc = collection.updateOne({ email: req.session.username }, {$set: { list_of_docs_bought: '2xx729' }})
```

however, this isn't going to work because I need to essentially insert a new id into there, not update it. But if I use `.insert()`, I am not sure if that is going to work because it will insert a totally new record instead of just into the array. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Have you checked out [$push](https://mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `upsert` which does exactly what you need.

Explanation below is taken from the [official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).

> - Creates a new document if no documents match the filter. For more details see upsert behavior.
> - Updates a single document that matches the filter.

So you would need to change your code to that:

```
let doc = collection.updateOne({ email: req.session.username }, {$push: { list_of_docs_bought: '2xx729' }}, { upsert: true })
```

Edit: You need to use the `$push` operator in order to add an element in an array. The `$set` operator will just overwrite it.

Comment: thanks for sharing! I tried your code. What happens is that it actually overwrites the list_of_docs_bought and changes the type to a string, and then the value of the string becomes 2xx729. So rather than updating the array it overwrote it and changed the data type as well.

Comment: @bobthebuilder I just edited my answer to `push` an element in the array instead of overwriting it.